# Using map on a conditional statement inside a mutate command

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing numbers that I would like to bin according to their absolute value.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(val = seq(-10, 10))
```

The following command accomplishes what I would like to do, but the values are hardcoded which I need to avoid:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(grp = case_when(abs(val) <= 5 ~ "Grp 1",
                         abs(val) <= 7 ~ "Grp 2",
                         TRUE ~ "Grp 3"))
```

How can I accomplish the same transformation, but instead using a named vector as the input:

```
grps <- c("Grp 1" = 5, "Grp 2" = 7)
```

So that I can add/remove groups as needed, for example, adding in `"Grp 3" = 9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `map` or something that works one-by-one, we can do it vectorized with `cut`:

```r
grps <- c("Grp 1" = 5, "Grp 2" = 7)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    grp = cut(abs(val), c(-Inf, grps, Inf), labels = c(names(grps), "Grp 3"))
  )
#    val   grp
# 1  -10 Grp 3
# 2   -9 Grp 3
# 3   -8 Grp 3
# 4   -7 Grp 2
# 5   -6 Grp 2
# 6   -5 Grp 1
# 7   -4 Grp 1
# 8   -3 Grp 1
# 9   -2 Grp 1
# 10  -1 Grp 1
# 11   0 Grp 1
# 12   1 Grp 1
# 13   2 Grp 1
# 14   3 Grp 1
# 15   4 Grp 1
# 16   5 Grp 1
# 17   6 Grp 2
# 18   7 Grp 2
# 19   8 Grp 3
# 20   9 Grp 3
# 21  10 Grp 3
```

Note that `grp` is a `factor`; if you want it to be `character`, just wrap it in `as.character`.

Comment: Thanks. That works, just need to make one adjustment for the final group number:
 `grp = cut(abs(val), c(-Inf, grps, Inf), labels = c(names(grps), paste("Grp", length(grps) + 1)))`, otherwise if you expand it to include say `"Grp 3" = 9` then your final group remains group 3 instead of automatically expanding to `Grp 4`.